# Comparing a function to a bound method in python 3

Tags: python-3.x

Consider a Python 3 program where bound methods are passed around in some manner. How does one compare the methods to the original functions which define them in the class definition? Or expressed in OOP terms: How does one check if a bound method is an instance of a function.

Lets examplify with some REPL-ing:

```python
>>> class C(object):
...   def m(self):
...     print("Calling m")
...
>>> o = C()
>>> print(o.m)
<bound method C.m of <__main__.C object at 0xb6f56d6c>>
>>> print(C.m)
<function C.m at 0xb6f4c6a4>
>>> if o.m == C.m:
...   print("Equality")
...
>>> if isinstance(o.m, C.m):
...   print("Relation")
...
Traceback ...
```

What I want to achieve above is to be able to check if o.m is related to C.m in some way.

Now of course we could take the string representations of C.m and o.m, with a regexp cut out the part which reads C.m, and end up with the result that o.m is related to C.m. But there must be a better way of dealing with this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that each method has a `__func__` field which holds the original function. In other words the comparison can be written as:

```
if o.m.__func__ == C.m:
      print("Equality")
```

Answer (score 4):

To see if two methods have the same underlying function object, use the `__func__` attribute:

```
>>> C.m == o.m.__func__
True
```

In Python 2, it is the `im_func` attribute.

This attribute is explained in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html).